# PostGIS query taking too long. >400ms

Tags: postgis, spatial-query

The query is:

```
Select COUNT(*) from highway_ref where (ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(highway_ref.geom,2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(73.919595 18.5622609)', 4326),2163),500))
```

I am trying to find the total number of roads which are within 500 metres from a particular lat long.

It's taking too long. How can I optimize it?

Comment: Did you create a spatial index, http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

Comment: You are projecting **every row** to evaluate this query (full table scan). 400ms indicates that it's a tiny table. I wouldn't use 2163 (which is spherical) for distance calculations, and would instead cast to geography and compute geodetic distance. If you index on `geography(geom)` (assuming your source is 4326), then ST_DWithin can use it. There are a number of examples of this, making this question a duplicate.

Comment: @artwork21 Yes I have created spatial index.

Comment: @Vince the table consists of 8000 rows. I still have to populate it with more data. I tried converting it to geography but there was no difference in time. Also i want the roads within 500 metres so had to convert to 2163. I wasn't able to specify distance in metres using 4263.

Comment: Another idea is to generate an envelope around that lat lng of 500 metres. Will it be fast?
What will be an effective query to do this?

Comment: I repeat, this question is a duplicate. If you search on the contents of your question, you ***will*** find examples which include proper use of a geography cast and an index of a geography cast (I know this becase I did that search a month ago). Using 2163 outside the US is wrong, so you can't use it to get proper results anyway. The information you added as comments belongs in the question. Please take the [Tour] to better understand how GIS SE works.

Comment: Vince, please vote to close if this is a duplicate